# Error when resetting password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

If a user is invited, but instead of clicking the invitation they go to the site and try to login, they get a "email already taken" message. They then try to use the password reset to gain access and get the error:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

bin/rails:

4 rescue LoadError => e
5  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
6 end
7 APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
8 require_relative '../config/boot'
9 require 'rails/commands'
```

The password reset works correctly for regular users who were not added through the invite system.

What's going wrong with the invite system? or maybe a better question, how do I start to debug that? Since the line given on the better errors page (line 9) is probably not the actual line giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong with your invite system, we don't know anything about it ;)

As it comes to debugging, you probably want to take a look at `byebug` (https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). It's probably already in your Gemfile. You can just put `byebug` anywhere in your code to get an interactive debug console right where you want to.

Comment: the issue was more specifically what to do when the line of code causing the issue isn't being shown.  btw, you should checkout pry gem.

Comment: also, it's not my invite system, its a gem, see the tags for the question